# How to set the TEXT color of a GridView cell?

Tags: .net, wpf, gridview, colors, cell

I tried this, but not only the text but also the border of the cell is set to Green. How do I set only the TEXT color to Green? Thanks.

```
e.Row.Cells[0].ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this one can help you.

[gridview row color](http://devilswork.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/how-to-make-a-gridview-row-color-cell-color-text-color/)

Comment: No, it does the same thing (set ForeColor) as what I did.

Comment: But I figured out the problem is with FireFox. IE and Chrome are OK.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.